# MySQL Escaping Needed After Inserting Data

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Do I need to use `mysqli_real_escape_string` when reusing data from a database for a query. The data was previously escaped so it can be safely inserted into the database. I am aware that when inserting data into a database, backslashes are removed.
Thanks.

Comment: I always use mysqli and placeholders for all my values so I don't have to worry about escaping as it's all handled by the method.

Comment: To show data you should use htmlspecialchars()

Comment: If you are aware of removed escaping - why do you ask? You need to use prepared statements instead of manual escaping anyway

Comment: Whoa. Quite a lot of answers for the question that could be another time just closed as a duplicate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you have to re-escape data that came from a DB when you're re-using it in another query. Consider escaping to be the equivalent of gift wrapping on a present. You "wrap" some data for the database in one query. It'll UNWRAP the data and put it in the data store. When you retrieve that data again later, the wrapping's gone and the data's "dangerous" again.

e.g. consider something like this:

```
$name = "Miles O'Brien"; 
$safe = mysql_real_escape_string($name);  // name becomes Miles O\'Brien
$sql = "INSERT INTO people (names) VALUES '$safe'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Now that name's in the database, but the escaping you performed is NOT PRESENT anymore - it was removed by the database as it processed the query, so if you do something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM people"
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_asssoc($result)) {
   $name = $row['name']; // get Miles O'Brien from the DB again
```

here you'll literally have retrieved `Miles O'Brien` with no escaping at all.

```
   $other_sql = "UPDATE ... WHERE name=$name";  <---INJECTION HERE
}
```

Escaping is not something you do only with "outside" data... *ANY* data you insert into a query string is "outside" data, even if you just got that data from the database just a few lines of code ago.

TL;DR: You can easily inject yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need it. The escapes are only used to make the query syntactically valid, they're not part of the data that's stored in the table. Any time you're interpolating strings into a query, you need to escape it.

As an example, suppose you have a table of full names, and there's someone with the last name `O'Reilly`. You perform a query to get this name into `$lname`, and then you want to use that variable in another query, e.g.

```
$query = "SELECT username WHERE last_name = '$lname'";
```

If you don't escape the string, the resulting query will be:

```
SELECT username WHERE last_name = 'O'Reilly'
```

As you can see, the quotes are not properly balanced. You need to escape it so that it will be:

```
SELECT username WHERE last_name = 'O\'Reilly'
```

However, if you use prepared queries with placeholders for these parameters, you don't need to worry about this much at all (in fact, it would be *wrong* to escape a variable that's bound to a placeholder, as you will then store the backslashes). This is generally preferred.

Also, consider NOT extracting and re-storing the data at all, but moving data around using SQL itself:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (last_name)
SELECT last_name
FROM Table2
WHERE ...
```

This is also likely to be more efficient, since the data doesn't have to move between the database and the application.

Comment: +1.  [This is a good answer],  "...if you use prepared queries *which use placeholders in the SQL text, and supply values with bind variables*, you don't need...". (I've seen examples of prepared statements that included values in SQL text, rather than as bind variables. I know, it made me shudder too.)

Answer (score 1):

That's not what escaping means.

Escaping text means inserting escape characters so that it can be inserted into a SQL string and be interpreted as the original text.
It has no effect on the actual value, unless you use the wrong escape characters.

You need to correctly escape your text every time you concatenate it into any kind of structured language.

When using SQL, you should ideally use parameters instead of concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of misunderstanding on the topic.

People keep using improper words, and a real danger coming from such a confusion.

**escaping** being confused with **safety**
**data** being confused with **strings**
**formatting** being confused with **trusting**

One have to sort these matters out.
Otherwise we still have an accepted answer implying that using `mysql_real_escape_string` does produce a "safe" variable. While it is not.

Comment: 'When I use a word,' Humpty Dumpty said, in rather a scornful tone, 'it means just what I choose it to mean — neither more nor less.'  -- Lewis Carroll, *Through the Looking Glass*.

Answer (score -2):

Just remember to validate properly all user inputted data that you plan on using and don't allow html or javascript code to be inserted. You also need to keep in mind XSS attacks, not just MySQL Injections. A good way to prevent xss is using htmlspecialchars() to convert HTML characters into HTML entities.

Comment: How will validation help when valid data can include special characters? A name like O'Reilly is valid, isn't it?